# Sending application specific messages

Tags: rest

There is a change to our business logic, where earlier with one of the APIs we use to return a list, for eg. list of employees. Recently we introduced authorization checks, to see if a particular user has permission to view a specific employee.

If say there are 10 employees that should be returned through method GET, due to the missing permission only 5 are returned. The request itself in this case is successful. I am currently not sure how to pass on the information back to the client that there were 5 employees that are filtered out due to missing permission.

1. Should this be mapped to HTTP status codes? If yes, which status code fits this? Or this is not an error at all?
2. What would be the best approach in this case?

Comment: I think a 200 return status would be the best.  As you've said, the request is successful.  Could you return JSON with one entry for the list and a second indicating the number filtered?  E.g. `{"employees": [...], "filtered": 5}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A status code by itself wouldn't be sufficient to indicate the partial response. The status code 206 sounds close by name but is used when a client specifically requests a partial set of data based on headers.

Use 200. The request was fulfilled successfully after all, and the reason for the smaller set of data is proprietary to your API so extra metadata in the response to indicate a message might be sufficient.

Assuming JSON response:

```
{
    "data": [ ... ],
    "messages": [
        "Only some data was returned due to permissions."
    ]
}
```

If you have many consumers and are worried about backward compatibility you may also want to provide a vendor specific versioned JSON media type:

```
"Content-Type": "application/vnd.myorg-v2+json"
```

Comment: Thanks Erik, this is quite helpful